How to Share Internet Access from Host to VM Using Internal Switch with ICS in Hyper-V?
Question:
I have a VM in Hyper-V that can connect to the internet using the host's Bridged Network adapter. For security reasons, I want to isolate the VM by using an Internal switch.
I’ve been told that I can still use the host's Bridged Network (which has internet access) and enable Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) to share the internet connection from the Bridged Network to the Internal switch.
However, I’m not sure if I need to create a new NAT network for this setup, or if there's a simpler way to configure this. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide to set this up correctly?
Here's what I’ve done so far:
Created an Internal switch in Hyper-V.
Enabled ICS on the host’s Bridged Network adapter to share the connection with the Internal switch.
Configured the VM’s network adapter to connect to the Internal switch.
Despite these steps, the VM still doesn’t have internet access. Any detailed instructions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
